# writing text inside image with python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am writing my calculation result as a text in the image.
In order to put a text in OpenCV, I write

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(resul, '**text**', (10,450), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

but my question is how can I update the text content each time when I am running the code. In other words, my code calculates a distance and gives a new result each time that I am running it. How can I update the text?

Comment: you want to clear a text on an image and add a new one, did i get your question right? (and that text doest have a bounding box, right? (cause if had it could be easy as masking the text!))

Comment: To @a-sam, My calculation of the distance between two objects changes when I am running my code for every image (in each image distance between two object changes) I just want to display my calculation on the image. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use [`format()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/) or if you're using Python 3, you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
distance = 10
cv2.putText(resul, 'Distance: {}'.format(distance), (10,450), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```